# ¿Cómo realizar un store procedure con paginación en SQL Server y enviar a un DataTable jQuery?

Tags: c#, ajax, sql-server, datatables

Tengo un *store procedure* que devuelve una lista de datos de gran tamaño y lo que deseo es paginarla para luego enviarla a mi JavaScript y llenar mi DataTable jQuery.

Controlador:

```
public JsonResult ObtenerEmpleados()
{
    List<Empleado> Empleados = GestionEmpleado.Instancia.ObtenerEmpleados();

    return Json(new { data = Empleados }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Deseo paginarla porque cuando trae demasiados registros me genera un error como el siguiente en el controlador:

```
Exceeds the value set in the `maxJsonLength.
```

Además, como debo recibirlo en mi *DataTable jQuery* para que cada vez que dé clic a un botón de paginación del *DataTable* realice las consultas al *store procedure* y solo obtenga los registros necesarios.

Mi DataTable jQuery:

```
var table = $("#tabla_mantTodosEmpleados").removeAttr('width').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: false,
    autoWidth: false,
    bDestroy: true,
    data: datos,
    columns: [
        {
            data: null,
            orderable: false
        },
        { data: "IdPersona", orderable: false },
        { data: "IdExterno", orderable: false },
        { data: "Nombre", orderable: false },
        {
            sClass: "text-center",
            render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<button class="btn btn-link text-center" type="button" id="btnEditar" onclick="MantEmpleados.obtenerDetalle(\'' + full.IdPersona + '\');" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Detalle"><i class="icon-eye"></i></button > ';
            }

        }

    ],
    /*columnDefs: [
        {
            sortable: false,
            "class": "index",
            targets: 0
        }

    ],*/
    language: {
        "decimal": "",
        "emptyTable": "No hay información",
        "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
        "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
        "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
        "infoPostFix": "",
        "thousands": ",",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "processing": "Procesando...",
        "search": "Buscar:",
        "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Primero",
            "last": "Ultimo",
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
        }
    }

});

table.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
    table.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
    });
}).draw();
```

Y dentro de mi *store procedure* solo contiene un `select` que trae 5000 registros:

```
select Id_Persona,Id_Externo,Nombre from Empleado
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32031/pagination-with-server-side-processing#Comment_86438

Comment: [Aquí hacen directamente el llamado al controlador para retornar data de manaera rapida](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40690/sample-implementation-of-serverside-processing-in-c-mvc-ef-with-paging-sorting-searching)

Answer (score 2):

Existen varias posibilidades de paginación en el procedure Sql.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Empleado (idPersona int, id_Externo int, Nombre varchar(10))
go
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.EmpleadosPaginados (@Pag int, @tamPag int)
As 
Begin
SELECT  T.idPersona,
        T.id_Externo,
        T.Nombre
FROM EMPLEADO t
ORDER BY T.idPersona
OFFSET(@pag - 1) * @tamPag ROWS
FETCH NEXT @TamPag ROWS ONLY;

END

INSERT INTO dbo.Empleado(idPersona, id_Externo, Nombre)
values
(1,1,'a'),
(2,2,'b'),
(3,3,'c'),
(4,4,'d'),
(5,5,'e'),
(6,6,'f'),
(7,7,'g'),
(8,8,'h'),
(9,9,'i');
go
exec dbo.EmpleadosPaginados @pag = 2, @tamPag = 2
```

[image: Salida]

[Paginar con Offset](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/10/22/paginar-consultas-como-estandar-ansi-offset-fetch/)

Otras opciones de paginación.

[Paginar con el operador Top](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/10/28/paginar-consultas-como-usando-el-top-2/)

[Paginar con RowNumber](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/10/28/paginados-usando-row_number-3/)

[Paginar con variables](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/11/19/paginados-utilizando-una-variable-de-tabla-con-ordenacion-en-funcion-de-una-variable-4/)

Comment: Como haría para que se integre a Datatable JQuery