# Cómo se puede crear 1 columna a partir de otras 6 columnas diferentes de forma permanente en SQL SERVER?

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos, visual-studio, concat

Bien el asunto es que la base de datos ya tiene datos ingresados y todo, es una base de datos directamente para el aprendizaje creada para los estudiantes pesa alrededor de 10gb, pero para el nombre y otros datos como dirección, email, teléfono aparece en columnas separadas, y busco concatenar todos los datos de nombre para que sea una sola columna:

> ***select top 100000 CONCAT(apellido1,+' '+ apellido2,+' '+apellido3,+'  '+nombre1+' '++' '+ nombre2,+' '+nombre3 ) as 'NOMBRES',
> AVENIDA,LETRA,NUMERO_C,COL,APDO,ZONA,CODGO_MUNI,CODGO_DE,ISOL
> from   PersonasBarrio***

Hasta allí todo bien, el problema es que veo que solo formo una columna virtual con el alias si no me equivoco claro, pero la idea es crear una columna permanente con el nombre completo, tomando en cuenta también que es una mala implementación por tener tener datos redundantes según he investigado, pero para referencia el catedrático nos pidió hacer una columna permanente con el nombre completo.

Cuando hago el query en Magnament Studio me arroja el resultado tal como deseo el nombre completo dentro de una columna pero no es columna permanente claro es virtual, por otro lado realmente no he podido implementarlo en C# y Visual Studio he usado éste código:

> **cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 100000 CONCAT(apellido1,+' '+ apellido2,+' '+apellido3,+' '+nombre1+' '++' '+ nombre2,+' '+nombre3 ) as 'NOMBRES', AVENIDA,LETRA,NUMERO_C,COL,APDO,ZONA,CODGO_MUNI,CODGO_DE,ISOL from PersonasBarrio WHERE NOMBRES LIKE ('" + ingresoDatos.Text + "%')   "**

Por ejemplo si hago otro WHERE:   ***WHERE apellido1 like ('" + ingresoDatos.Text + "%') AND apellido2 like  ('" + ingresoDatos.Text + "%')   ";*** si arroja los resultados pero 1 tarda mucho y otras se "flipa", estaba leyendo sobre *linq en C#* pero tampoco le cojo mucho el rumbo no sé si es por memoria que el programa no corre. Entonces en síntesis primero cómo puedo hacer una columna permanente con la concatenación he leído sobre las funciones UPDATE y ALTER pero aún no le cojo el rumbo para poder hacerlo, y segunda pregunta como puedo mostrar en el DataGridView buscando solo con el nombre completo en C# con visual studio si pudiesen orientarme muchas gracias!

PD
Perdón por formular mal la pregunta anteriormente sin código y sin muchos argumentos de investigación. bien a continuación el código que he hecho hasta el momento:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace FILTRARDATOS  
     public partial class filtradoprincipal : Form
    {

        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SERVER\SERVER;Initial Catalog=DStudents;Integrated Security=True");

        public filtradoprincipal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void filtradoprincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ingresoDatos_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            conexion.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = conexion.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 100000 CONCAT(apellido1,+' '+ apellido2,+' '+apellido3,+' '+nombre1+' '++' '+ nombre2,+' '+nombre3 ) as 'NOMBRES', AVENIDA,LETRA,NUMERO_C,COL,APDO,ZONA,CODGO_MUNI,CODGO_DE,ISOL from PersonasBarrio WHERE NOMBRES LIKE ('" + ingresoDatos.Text + "%')   " 
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ad.Fill(dt);
            dgvDatos.DataSource = dt;


            conexion.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**##Actualización##**
Tomando en cuenta los comentarios y sugerencias  que me han dado pues realicé otro código con consulta sin hacer otra columna. Pero resulta como dije anteriormente la base de datos es enorme con datos replicados pero el profesor nos dijo que aunque fueran replicados quiere los más de 8 millones de registros en el DGV, que básicamente nos había pedido realizar una columna uniendo las otras columnas correspondientes a los nombres y apellidos para que termináramos investigando y dándonos cuenta que si era mala implementación...

Se pudiera decir que se soluciona el problema pero **NO!** Debido a que cuando ejecuto el código de consultas de esa tabla(ya que estamos trabajando con formularios en C#) me arroja el error ***System.OutOfMemoryExceptions***
y bueno investigando sobre ello dice que es común cuando las Tablas son de datos grandes, y que la recomendación en la pagina de Microsoft es:

> ***Si está usando un DataTable para completar un elemento de la interfaz de usuario como un control GridView, use la paginación para que solo se devuelvan unos pocos registros a la vez.***

Bueno pero ahí está el detalle ahora que estoy investigando sobre el paginado en el DGV...

Éste es el código que hice nuevamente no sé si tienen alguna sugerencia me sería de mucha ayuda en mi aprendizaje muchas gracias de antemano!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Proyecto.Forms
{
    public partial class formCons : Form
    {
        public formCons()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        DataSet resultados = new DataSet();
        DataView mfil;

        public void leerDatos(string query, ref DataSet dstPrincipal, string tabla)
        {
            try
            {
                string cadena = (@"Data Source=SERVER\SERVER;Initial Catalog=DStudents;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cadena);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                cn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dstPrincipal, tabla);
                da.Dispose();
                cn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            
        }

        private void formCons_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.leerDatos("SELECT apellido1,apellido2,apellido3,nombre1,nombre2,nombre3, AVENIDA,LETRA,NUMERO_C,COL,APDO,ZONA,CODGO_MUNI,CODGO_DE,ISOL from PersonasBarrio", ref resultados, "PersonasBarrio");

            this.mfil = ((DataTable)resultados.Tables["PersonasBarrio"]).DefaultView;

            this.dgvDatosN.DataSource = mfil;

        }

        private void tboxConsultaBD_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            string exit_data = "";
            string[] search_words = this.tboxConsultaBD.Text.Split(' ');

            foreach (string palabra in search_words)
            {
                if (exit_data.Length == 0)
                {
                    exit_data = "(apellido1 LIKE '%" + palabra + "%' OR apellido2 LIKE '%" + palabra + "%' OR nombre1 LIKE '%" + palabra + "%' OR nombre2 LIKE '%" + palabra + "%')";

                }
                else
                {
                    exit_data += "AND (apellido1 LIKE '%" + palabra + "%' OR apellido2 LIKE '%" + palabra + "%' OR nombre1 LIKE '%" + palabra + "%' OR nombre2 LIKE '%" + palabra + "%')";
                }
            }

            this.mfiltro.RowFilter = exit_data;
        }
    }
}
```

De momento no tengo que usar botones para hacer la consulta solo simplemente ingresar en el textBox pero tomando en cuenta lo que he aprendido con CRUD creo que no tendría problemas.

**P.D
No sé si tengo que cambiar el título de la pregunta y/o mover a otro lado ésto perdón :/**

**NUEVA ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Bueno Investigando pues llegamos al final que todo se debe hacer bajo paginación y justamente @CristinaCarrasco me sugirió también eso que me ha ayudado mucho a guiarme sobre éste proyecto e hice el siguiente procedure en SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GenteBD
@inicio int, @final int
as
declare @TablaAux table
(
Idl int,
Nombre nvarchar(100),
Calle nvarchar(111),
Letra nvarchar(1),
No_Casa nvarchar(8),
Apdo nvarchar(6),
Colonia nvarchar(80),
Zona numeric(2,0),
Cod_Mun numeric(2,0),
Cod_Dep numeric(2,0)
)


INSERT INTO @TablaAux (Idl, Nombre, Calle,No_Casa,Apdo,Colonia,Zona,Cod_Mun,Cod_Dep)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Idl asc)Idl, Nombre, Calle,No_Casa,Apdo,Colonia,Zona,Cod_Mun,Cod_Dep FROM PersonasBarrio
SELECT * FROM @TablaAux where Idl between @inicio and @final
GO
```

Luego en C# hice una clase que la llamé Gente la volví pública:

```
private int Idl;
        private string Nombre;
        private string Calle;
        private string Letra;
        private string No_Casa;
        private string Apdo;
        private string Colonia;
        private float Zona;
        private float Cod_Mun;
        private float Cod_Dep;
        private int Inicio;
        private int Final;


        public int Idl1 { get { return Idl; } set { Idl = value; } }
        public string Nombre1 { get { return Nombre; } set { Nombre = value; } }
        public string Calle1 { get { return Calle; } set { Calle = value; } }
        public string LETRA1 { get { return LETRA; } set { LETRA = value; } }
        public string No_Casa1 { get { return No_Casa; } set { No_Casa = value; } }
        public string Apdo1 { get { return Apdo; } set { Apdo = value; } }
        public string Colonia1 { get { return Colonia; } set { Colonia = value; } }
        public float Zona1 { get { return Zona; } set { Zona = value; } }
        public float Cod_Mun1 { get { return Cod_Mun; } set { Cod_Mun = value; } }
        public float Cod_Dep1 { get { return Cod_Dep; } set { Cod_Dep = value;  } }
        public int Inicio1  { get { return Inicio; } set { Inicio = value; } }
        public int Final1 { get { return Final; }  set { Final = value; } }

        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SERVER\SERVER;Initial Catalog=DStudents;Integrated Security=True");

        public DataSet ListarGente()
        {
             SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("sp_GenteBD", conexion);
             comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inicio", Inicio1);
             comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@final", Final1);
             SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
             DataSet dt = new DataSet();
             da.Fill(dt);
             return dt;
        }
```

Luego pues ya trabajé el código tal como vi en el vídeo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Gente objp = new Gente();
        DataSet dsTabla;
        int PagInicio = 1, Indice = 0, NumFilas = 20, PagFinal;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PagFinal = NumFilas;
            CargarDG();
        }


        private void CargarDG()
        {
            objp.Inicio1 = PagInicio;
            objp.Final1 = PagFinal;
            dsTabla = objp.ListarGente();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dsTabla.Tables[1];

            int cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(dsTabla.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()) / NumFilas;

            if (Convert.ToInt32(dsTabla.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()) % NumFilas > 0) cantidad++;

            textBox2.Text = cantidad.ToString();
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();

            for (int x = 1; x <= cantidad; x++)
                comboBox1.Items.Add(x.ToString());

            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = Indice;
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int pagina = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text);
            Indice = pagina - 1;
            PagInicio = (pagina - 1) * NumFilas + 1;
            PagFinal = pagina * NumFilas;
            CargarDG();
        }
     

    }
```

Bueno probé con el combobox tal como en el vídeo aunque en mi caso tiene que ser por medio de búsqueda en un texbox(no hay problema con ello), si compiló y corre el programa el problema que poseo es que es muy lento extremadamente lento alrededor de 2 minutos para que pase de página entonces no sé qué estoy haciendo mal he probado primero obvio ir bajando el número de filas hasta llegar a 20 e igual... Probé otro método con Linq y sigue lo mismo siendo consciente que es una big data de más de 5.4 millones de registros, alguien puede orientarme? Gracias!

Comment: Saludos, 2 cosillas: 1. Bienvenido/a a SOes. 2. Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 (hay bonus links en los detalles). TL;DR: Realiza el recorrido y mejora la pregunta antes que te den negativos y/o te la cierren por estar ajena a los lineamientos del sitio.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Hace falta más información en tu pregunta para poder ayudarte. Deberías añadir el DDL de la tabla para saber los tipos de campos y si los mismos son *nulables* o no. Además, es necesario saber cómo se recibe el dato o valor a buscar en la base de datos. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para agregar lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: La caracteristica del motor de base de datos Sql Server que busca es la de columnas computadas o calculadas (computed columns). El ejercicio al que se enfrenta es de carácter académico, por lo que a manera de comentario le refiero el enlace https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Muchas gracias plantearé nuevamente la pregunta!

Comment: Hola, bueno por donde empezar, no tiene sentido hacer una columna permanente con "Todas las columnas" eso es precisamente lo que se quiere evitar al crear bases de datos.  Si vamos atras antes todo se guardaba en un solo archivo, despues evolucionaron las computadoras y se crearon las bases de datos, entonces partiendo de esto, no es buena idea crear una columna extra con todas las columnas juntas, para eso puedes crear una VISTA (View) en sql y hacer un select a la vista desde c#

Comment: El tener una sola columna no mejorará el rendimiento. Es importante que uses consultas que puedan aprovechar los índices para que no se tenga que leer toda la tabla al buscar datos.

Comment: A todos muchas gracias por responder, bien en efecto  mala implementación concatenar varias columnas para listar pero el profesor nos había dicho que uniéramos los nombres y apellidos (tienen en total 6 columnas ) pero ayer nos dijo que mostremos en el DGV las 6 columnas y  se supondría que todo estaría bien salvo que 'System.OutOfMemoryException' a la hora de ejecutar la consulta con C# y DGV ya que son literalmente cientos de miles de datos replicados. Hice una View como @CristinaCarrasco me sugirió. Gracias ahora estoy viendo como hago para evitar ese error, pero no sé como con la consulta.

Comment: para evitar esto: OutOfMemoryException puedes utilizar un "paginado", eso se hace comunmente en los sitemas con eso solo consultas por ejemplo top 50, osea vas consultando los datos por paginas o por bloques, una forma facil de hacer el paginado es crear un stored procedure el cual reciba el # de pagina y elmentos por pagina... tambien lo puedes hacer con entity framework y linq <--- consultados "todo" pero solo cargas en memoria lo que muestres en pantalla

Comment: Lo que te digo del entity framework... es que con linq puedes "pre-crear el query" y se crea una variable IEnumerable<TuVista> esta variable tiene tu "query" pero no carga los datos en memoria.. sino que los puedes iterar uno por uno o hacer sub consultas de esos datos.

Comment: aqui hay un ejemplo de como cresar un stored procedure para "paginar"

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329588/c%C3%B3mo-realizar-un-store-procedure-con-paginaci%C3%B3n-en-sql-server-y-enviar-a-un-dat

Comment: Si gracias @CristinaCarrasco, de hecho empecé eso ayer, hice un procedure en sql con variables de inicio-final e hice una consulta y en C# logré que corriera sin el error antes mencionado pero la consulta sigue siendo extremadamente lenta aunque le ponga 25 filas ya que es una big data estamos hablando mas o menos de 5,430,000 registros pero ya probando con 2 métodos diferentes de paginación en el DGV con C# no sé formular bien el query en el procedure o bien algo estoy haciendo sumamente mal :/

Comment: Si hay 5 millones de registros, y haces un like, sin tener un indice, la consulta va a ser lenta! y con un like, va a ser mas lenta... Para esas cosas se usan elastic search y otro tipo de ayudas. No va a ser mas rapido, y menos con una columna de ese tipo. No busques optimizar algo que no vas a poder optimizar. Y si tu profesor te dice que esta bien mostrar por pantalla 80 millones de registros, yo huiria... a nadie le sirven 80 millones de registros en una pantalla.. o aca alguien (inclusive google) te muestra tanta informacion junta?

Comment: @gbianchi gracias, por eso mismo estoy en paginación con dgv en C# como muestro en la actualización de la pregunta, pero aún poseo el problema que es muy pero muy lenta la consulta, claro que el problema soy yo en ese caso jejeje pero estoy investigando como hacer para hacer una consulta más efectiva en sql y poder en C# implementarlo de la mejor manera

Comment: Eso que mencionas es un muy buen comienzo :)  yo creo que vas por buen camino :)