# ¿Cómo puedo implementar paginación en C# .net core 5 sin usar entity framework?

Tags: c#, webapi

Cómo podría implementar paginación sin usar entity framework, a partir de una lista de datos ya procesados.

Contexto:
Ya obtengo los datos mediante un query, lo que necesito es retornar esos datos, paginados en una api.

Comment: pues pagina el query... no entiendo la pregunta...

Comment: Cómo paginaría el query?

Comment: y depende el query, la base de datos, tu api... EF es una ayuda, pero para paginar el query no necesitas EF....

Comment: Y la investigación? Qué has intentado? Qué palabras utilizaste en Google? Yo busqué "SQL Server pagination" y muchos resultados de búsqueda resuelven tu pregunta. Hay algo **específico** que no te esté funcionando? En EF se pagina usando `.Skip()` y `.Take()`. Tal vez quieras empezar buscando el equivalente en SQL Server.

Comment: pues desde tu tabla o grid debes enviar el numero de pagina que requieres, y tu respuesta debe contener el numero de registros predeterminado ejemplo 10,50, etc.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo realizar un store procedure con paginación en SQL Server y enviar a un DataTable jQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329588/c%c3%b3mo-realizar-un-store-procedure-con-paginaci%c3%b3n-en-sql-server-y-enviar-a-un-dat)

Comment: He encontrado una posible solución. 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20;

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/509567/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-implementar-paginaci%c3%b3n-en-c-net-core-5-sin-usar-entity-framework?noredirect=1#comment905221_509567

Muchas gracias por los comentarios, ayudaron a despejar algunas dudas.